# Node.js can't compile my .js files (OSX Yosemite)

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, terminal

I'm running node.js on my macbook pro and i really can't understand why everytime i try to compile something by my terminal i get this error:

```
MBPdiFrancesco:~ francescocolonnese$ node -p
> /Users/francescocolonnese/Desktop/appunti.js 
SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'francescocolonnese'
    at new RegExp (native)
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
```

can someone help me through this..?

Comment: Can you show the problematic code please?

Comment: sure @informaniac ! i'll text it below..but it happens for all .js files that i put on the terminal after running node. here it's an example:

**var ciao =12;**
**var boh = “nooo”;**
**console.log(ciao+boh);**


as you can see, the code is really simple, but it does not work. It happens as well with much more complicated codes.

Comment: What version of Node are you using?
I see you've got some strange quotes around your string - make sure these are regular quotes; it works for me when I fix them - but I cannot reproduce the `SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'francescocolonnese'` error.
Are you supplying the exact code your Node is failing on?

Comment: yep, i just tried with several different files, and i get the same error for each one of them. **i'm using node 0.12.2** .

Comment: By the way, i corrected the quotes, and i get this:


SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:44:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:117:23)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10)

Comment: Please paste the *exact* code you were using above to cause this error.

Comment: var ciao =12; 
var boh = ‘nooo’; 
console.log(ciao+boh);

this is the exact code....i think the problem is not of the code..

Comment: Aha! Now we're getting somewhere...
I would suggest that you completely uninstall and reinstall node - did you upgrade recently or somehow manage to accidentally edit one of its internal files?

Comment: i don't think so...i reinstalled it 10 minutes ago because of this..is there a way TO COMPLETE UNINSTALL IT?probably i could have deleted it in a wrong way..i just downloaded the version from node's site..

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Ah, sorry :)
You're reinstalling using their `.pkg` file? I would suggest maybe using `Homebrew` instead.

Comment: [link](https://changelog.com/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x/)
i followed this guide to install node but i get this:    

Warning: node-0.12.2_1 already installed, it's just not linked.

_when i try to use npm it says "command not found"

Comment: `brew link node --force`

Comment: 'MBPdiFrancesco:~ francescocolonnese$ brew link node --force
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.2_1... 
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait, are you trying to run a js file by typing it's name in the node interactive shell? If so, the reason for the error is simple. It's because:

```
/Users/francescocolonnese/Desktop/appunti.js
```

is not valid javascript code. Indeed, looking at the error you can see that node tries to interpret `//` as a regular expression as:

```
/Users/francescocolonnese
```

and complains that `francescocolonnese` is not a valid regex switch.

Inside the node shell you should only type valid javascript. If you insist on doing this you can type this:

```
require('/Users/francescocolonnese/Desktop/appunti.js')
```

But that's the wrong way to do it. Instead simply ask node.js to run that file:

```
node -p /Users/francescocolonnese/Desktop/appunti.js
```

Comment: MBPdiFrancesco:~ francescocolonnese$ node
> node -p /Users/francescocolonnese/mail.js
ReferenceError: node is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:132:27)
    at bound (domain.js:254:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:267:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:279:12)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:214:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:553:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:830:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:109:10

Comment: run `node -p /Users/francescocolonnese/Desktop/appunti.js` from the bash prompt (`$`), not from the node prompt (`>`)

Comment: @FrancescoColonnese: If you still insist on running a script inside the node interactive shell, use `require` as I mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

*"@infomaniac - I would try deleting this whole folder: /usr/local/share/systemtap/"*

worked for me, thanks!

Uninstall node.js

`brew uninstall node`

`brew uninstall node --force`

Output from `brew doctor`:

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.4... 
Error: Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.

Remove /usr/local/share/systemtap/

`$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/systemtap/`

Reinstall node.js

`brew install node`

Fix unlinked kegs

`$ brew link node`

Output:

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.4... 6 symlinks created

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the node version you installed from `nodejs.org`, and then run:

`brew update`

`brew uninstall node --force`

`brew install node`

Comment: Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link node
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`

Comment: Try running all of the above as `sudo`

Comment: i get this when i run "sudo brew install node"

Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.

Comment: I would try deleting this whole folder:
`/usr/local/share/systemtap/`